# How to filter columns containing hyperlinks in r DT

Tags: r, dt

I have a column "url" which contains hyperlinks. The link texts are integers. How can I make the column filtering work in DataTables so that the filtering is performed using the link texts instead of the html of the hyperlink? Below is an example:

```
library(DT)
df <- data.frame(Val = c("A", "B"), url = c("<a href='https://www.google.com'>1</a>", "<a href='https://www.google.com'>2</a>"))
datatable(df, escape = FALSE, filter = list(position = "top"))
```

In the above datatable I would like to filter the rows based on the values 1 and 2 in the url column. Here's what currently happens
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8sih.png)

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, it looks like it does exactly what you are asking already. Are you trying to filter the URL column based on the 1 and 2?

Comment: I edited the example I gave. What I would like to do is filter the rows based on the values 1 and 2 in the url column. It was a bit misleading as I also had 1 and 2 in the val column, so I changed them to A and B.

Comment: Oh I see now, that not how I would expect it to behave either!

Answer (score 2):

```
library(DT)

render <- c(
  "function(data, type, row){",
  "  if(type === 'display'){",
  "    var a = '<a href=\"' + row[3] + '\">' + data + '</a>';",
  "    return a;",
  "  } else {",
  "    return data;",
  "  }",
  "}"
)

df <- data.frame(
  Val = c("A", "B"), 
  url = c("google", "stackoverflow"),
  href = c("https://www.google.com", "https://www.stackoverflow.com")
)
datatable(df, escape = FALSE, filter = list(position = "top"), 
          options = list(
            columnDefs = list(
              list(targets = 2, render = JS(render)),
              list(targets = 3, visible = FALSE)
            )
          )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the url text to be integers? If not, a quick and dirty way is to reconstruct the html node to make the url's string visible.

I.e.

```
df <- data.frame(Val = c(1,2), url = c("<a href='https://www.google.com'>1</a>", "<a href='https://www.bbc.com'>2</a>")      
df$string_url <-paste("<a href ='", (str_match(df$url, "'(.*?)'")[,2]), "'>", (str_match(df$url, "'(.*?)'")[,2]), "</a>", sep = "" )    
datatable(df[c("Val","string_url")], escape = FALSE, filter = list(position = "top"))
```

Comment: I think I formulated my question poorly. Please see the comment I made above.